# What statistical test should be used to assess for differences in knowledge retention of the same group of participants at 4 different time points?

Tags: optimization, interpretation, experiment-design

I am conducting a study to assess knowledge retention rates among a group of students over a period of time. Participants took a quiz at baseline, after a lesson, 3 months later, and then 1 year later. The quiz was identical each time, and the group of participants were the same each time. What test can I use to assess for significant differences in scores among the 4 different time points? The quiz was 10 points, and students received a score in full points only (i.e. 0/10, 1/10, 2/10, etc. or 0%, 10%, 20%, etc.).

Comment: If you are referring to testing a null hypothesis, the null hypothesis is almost impossible to be true for your type of study and measurements, so p-values will not be as helpful as you think.  Concentrate on state which quantities you want to._estimate_ and getting uncertainty intervals for those quantities.  “Significant difference” means almost nothing.